# How do I pass parameters to a viewmodel in ViewModelLocator?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

We're using MVVM Light for a WPF app we're working on. All of our viewmodels, to date, don't require any parameter passed to their constructors. I'm working on the first that will and its likely we'll have others. Here's what we've got for one of our VM declared as a property in the ViewModelLocator:

```
static public OrderLineViewModel OrderLineVM
{
get
{
    if (ServiceLocator.IsLocationProviderSet)
    {
        SimpleIoc ioc = ServiceLocator.Current as SimpleIoc;
        return ioc.GetInstanceWithoutCaching<OrderLineViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The OrderLineViewModel is one where we'll be using the default constructor and one where I've defined a constructor with 2 nullable parameters:

```
public OrderLineViewModel(long? OrderID, long? ProductID)
```

In the declaration for OrderLineVM, how do I specify the parameter OrderID, for example? (I'll want to pass a null for ProductID.)

I should mention that I'm always trying to use a declaration of a command in a class based upon MessageBase. The command, such as I have it at this point (it is incomplete), looks like this:

```
private void ExecuteViewOrderLineWithParmsCommand(object parameter)
{
    string value = parameter as string; //this is the OrderID
    //not sure how to get the OrderID information using the OpenViewMessage class below
    OpenViewMessage message = new OpenViewMessage();
    CurrentViewModel = message.ViewModel = ViewModelLocator.OrderLineVM;
}
```

Comment: By any chance, would this help your case? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5539953